# Count sub folders in given folder

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, query, subfolders, count

So this is my query to count items in given folder:

`/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/Shared%20Documents/')/ItemCount`

And it gives me count of all elements but how I can count only folders inside `/Shared%20Documents/` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can examine the returned XML to find related querries for your request...

There is no nice way to just pull the folder count, but you can use the /folders to retrieve all folders below the current node.

See this line from the returned XML for your query:

```
<link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Folders" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="Folders" href="Web/GetFolderByServerRelativePath(decodedurl='/teams/TeamsiteTestHeiko/Shared%20Documents')/Folders" />
<title />
```

Calling that on my root DocLib with **2 folders** returns the correct answer of **3 folders** since you will also be getting the Forms folder in the root level.

Hope that helps

Comment: I did it the same way. I just get basic info about all folders and count them. I was just looking for nicer way to do it.

Comment: I am guessing this will become a tree view. Only fetch the items once you expand a folder. Show the expand icon regardless and remove it onClick if no items are returned, if items come back. This can save a ton of requests